# If $ab - a'b' = \pm 1$, then $(a + a', b + b') = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If $ab - a'b' = \pm 1$, then can view the linear equation as a linear combination, that leads to the r.h.s. being a multiple of $\gcd$. With that having modulus of $1, \gcd =1$.

Also, the possible co-prime pairs are :  $(a,a')=(a,b')=(b,a')=(b,b') =1$. This also means that there two (possibly?) composite number pairs that mutually co-prime, as:

$a = 7, b = 14, a'= 5, b'=15$.

Q.1. Is it possible for $(a,b)=1$, and / or $(a',b')=1$, i.e. for them to be also co-prime; and hence there being 'possibly' $6$ or even $5$ pairs of co-prime numbers.

Coming back, need some integers $x,y$ s.t. $(a+a')x \pm (b+b')y =1$, i.e. the linear combination of $(a+a')$ and $(b+b')$ is $0$ for some integers $x,y$.

I want a solution that is based only on number theory without any recourse to determinants (i.e., effectively linear algebra).

*Addendum*  In wake of answer by @DanielWainfleet, have added link to a [simple diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st9dG.png), that does not help me in improving understanding.

Comment: Consider $a=b=a'=1$, $b'=0$.

Comment: Yes, but if some sort of significance in geometrical or even in terms of determinants were attached to having $6$ (as you have shown), or $5$ co-prime pairs were there. I feel that at this level, finding a suitable number(s) is not having any meaning attached. I don't want to feel like a school kid, practicing problems without understanding any significance.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\gcd( a + a', b + b' ) = 1$ if $ab - a'b' = \pm 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24332)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Hence, I stated (initially) in my OP that determinants should not be used. But, this answer has no clue to the question of what it means by $4,5,6$ co-prime pairs. If there could be some pointer to that.

Comment: Let $ab-a'b'=\pm 1$. Then each of the pairs $(a,a'),(a,b'),(b,b'),(b,a')$ are co-prime. It may be that $\gcd (a,b)\ne 1\ne \gcd(a',b'),$ e.g. $(a,b)=(8,8), $ $(a',b')=(3,21).$  By the Chinese Remainder Theorem there  exists $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $\gcd (a,b+na')=1=\gcd(a', b+na)=\pm 1$. And with $b_1=b+na'$ and $b'_1=b'+na$ we have $ab_1-a'b'_1=ab-a'b'$. I dk  what else to say.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks a lot for your kind help. I will try to post soon any exploration over it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I hope you meant in your earlier comment: $\gcd(a^{'}, b^{'}+na)$ instead of $gcd(a^{'}, b+na)$.

Comment: If $ab-a'b'=1$ then the set of all $(c,c')$ such that $ac-a'c'=1$ is $\{(b+na',b'+na)\}.$ By th Chinese Remainder Theorem there exists $n$ with $b+na'\equiv 1 \pmod a$  and $b'+na\equiv 1\pmod {a'}.$ So with $c=b+na'$ and $c'=b'+na $ we have $ac-a'c'=1,$ with $1=\gcd (a',c')=\gcd (a',b'+na)$, as I wrote.

Comment: Thanks for vindication, but I am unable to see significance behind the choice of terms beyond the cancellation of like terms with opposite signs. I mean that it is possible to choose only $c=b+na'$, & $ c' = b'+na$, as this leads to cancellation of $naa'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the request (in comments from the proposer) for a "geometric intuition":

Notation : $(x,y)$ is an ordered pair.

If $p=(x,y)$ and $p'=(x',y')$ are points in $\Bbb R^2$ then the area of the triangle with vertices $p,p',$ and $(0,0)$ is $\frac {1}{2}|xy'-x'y|.$ (An area $0$ means that $p,p',$ and $(0,0)$ are co-linear.)

So if $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ and there exists a point $(x',y')\in \Bbb Z^2$ such that  the area of the triangle with  vertices $(x,y), (x',y'),(0,0)$ is $\frac {1}{2},$ then $|xy'-x'y|=1,$ which implies that $\gcd(x,y)=1.$

If $|ab-a'b'|=1$ then the parallelogram $P$ with vertices $(0,0), (a,b'),(a',b),(a+a',b'+b)$ has area $1$ because it is twice the area of the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(a,b'),(a',b).$ But the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(a+a',b'+b),(a,b')$ also has half the area that $P$ does, so it has area $\frac {1}{2}.$  Applying the preceding paragraph when $a,a',b,b'\in \Bbb Z,$ with $(x,y)=(a+a',b'+b)$  and $(x',y')= (a,b'),$ we have $\gcd (a+a',b'+b)=1.$

Comment: I hope to understand it soon, and will put questions if needed. I hope you meant: different characters at two places: (i) "An area $0$ means that $p, p'$", (ii) $(x',y') = (a',b')$. I would also request you to please tell the significance of $4$, $5$ or $6$ co-prime pairs arising out of the equality : $ab - a'b' = \pm 1$.

Comment: "  $ p,q$  " was a typo. But I do mean $(x',y')=(a,b')$, which is one of the vertices of the parallelogram.

Comment: Drawing a diagram may help to understand it.

Comment: While drawing, I saw in your third para. the starting line, "If |$ab - a'b'$|". I am confused, and feel it should be in sync with earlier para, i.e. "|$xy' - x'y$|". Also, the diagram as shown in my edited OP's addendum is not helpful in understanding. The points $p,p'$ have coordinates $(x,y), (x',y')$.

Comment: Please respond as I hope this (diagram's) errors will form the crux to understanding.

Comment: In the diagram, add the segment joining $p$ and $p'.$ Then $\triangle Opp' ,$ with $O=(0,0),$ has area $1/2$ because $|xy'-x'y|=1.$ But  the triangle with vertices $O, p$, and $p+p'$ has the same area:Half the area of the parallelogram . (We can compute it directly as $(1/2)|x[y+y']-y[x+x']|=(1/2)|xy'-yx'|=(1/2)$ as in the A by Michael Rozenberg.)  The notations between $x,y$,etc., and $a,b,$ etc. are not "in sync".

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if (i.e., $x,y,a,b$ and $x',y',a',b'$) are not in sync; then $a,b,a',b'$ are used only for demonstration. Also, can you please please provide some hint towards $4,5,6$ co-prime pairs' significance geometrically or by any other logic as determinants (i.e., effectively linear algebra). I  mean significance for each of the three cases individually.

Comment: I dk about that..

Comment: Sir, thanks for being very clear but cannot we explore with some hint from your side. I hope mathematics involved would be quite simple, just exploration is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Because $$(a+a')b-(b+b')a'=\pm1.$$

Comment: Nice, but my Q.1, if possible be also answered. Also, some sort of geometric intuition, if possible, be attached to choosing only a particular set of values to be the integer multiplier ( i.e. $(b,a')$ or (b',a)). I cannot choose the integer multiplier to be : $(a/a',b/b')$.